form data ulpoad with formidable@v2,node js and mongodb is returning an empty object while i submited form data with photo file
an using my postman to send a form data request but it is returning an empty object. am using formidable @v2 for the form data upload
const formidable= require('formidable');
const _ = require("lodash");
const fs= require("fs");
const Product= require("../models/product.js");

exports.create=  (req,res)=>{
    let form= new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.KeepExtensions= true;
    form.parse(req,(err, fields,files)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({error:"image could not be uploaded"})
        }
        let product= new Product(fields)
        if(files.photo) {
   
            if (files.photo.size > 1000000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error:"image should be less than 1mb",
                });
            }
              product.photo.data= fs.readFileSync(files.photo.filepath);
            
            product.photo.contentType=files.photo.mimetype
            
        }
        try{
            const productdb=  product.save();
            res.json(productdb);
        }catch(err){
            
           return res.status(400).json({errror: 'error 404'})
           
        }

